# I have a somewhat (read: EXTREMELY) broken hitwall function and I don't see what I am doing wrong

Tags: java, radians

Alright, now I am working on a small derp-ish game based on Brownian motion, and I am working on a hit-wall function for the particles, but it isn't working. Basically, I am expressing the direction of the particles in radians, and whenever it hits a wall, I add Pi radians to the direction to flip it, but for some reason, it either isn't getting called or not working. These are the peices of code I have, any suggestions are welcome.

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Particle implements Actor {
protected double xPos;
protected double yPos;
protected Velocity v;
protected Color hue;
protected boolean needsUpdate;

public Particle(){
    this((Math.random()*500),(Math.random()*500),new Velocity((int)(Math.random()*500),(Math.random()*Velocity.TAU)));
}

public Particle(double x, double y, Velocity vel){
    xPos=x;
    yPos=y;
    v=vel;
    hue=Color.red;
    needsUpdate=false;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(hue);
    g.fillOval((int)xPos, (int)yPos, 16, 16);
}

public void act() {
    xPos+=v.getSlopefromDirection();
    yPos+=1;
}

public void onHitWall(int dir) {
    v.setDirection((v.getDirection()+Math.PI)%(Math.PI*2));     
}

public void onHitOther(Actor other) {

}

public boolean canCollide() {
    return true;
}

public int getLeftX() {
    return (int)xPos;
}

public int getRightX() {
    return (int)xPos+4;
}

public int getTopY() {
    return (int)yPos;
}

public int getBottomY() {
    return (int)yPos+4;
}
```

}

And this is the class I am using to display it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Feild extends JFrame{
protected ArrayList<Actor> actors;
private final int size=500;
protected Thread th;

public Feild(ArrayList<Actor> a){
    super("A Brownian Love Story");
    setSize(size, size);
    actors=a;
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    th = new Thread();
    while(true){
        paint(getGraphics());
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    //g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    for(int i=0;i<actors.size();i++){
        if(actors.get(i).getLeftX()<=0)
            actors.get(i).onHitWall(1);
        if(actors.get(i).getRightX()>=500)
            actors.get(i).onHitWall(2);
        if(actors.get(i).getTopY()<=0)
            actors.get(i).onHitWall(1);
        if(actors.get(i).getBottomY()>=500)
            actors.get(i).onHitWall(2);
        actors.get(i).act();
        actors.get(i).draw(g);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){out.println(i);}
}



}
```

So i tried changing the paint function to checking for collisions after acting, and it still looks like onHitWall is getting skipped over, even though after putting in a print statement it isn't.

Comment: First off, it's a "Field", not a "Feild". Now, what is a `Velocity`? Also, you should at least attempt to debug the code before asking for help - inserting a print statement into `onHitWall` is trivial. Finally, "it's not working" is not a helpful description of the problem. What does it do?

Comment: 1.) Slip of the fingers I didn't bother to correct.
2.) From the description it can be inferred that it is essentially a data structure that holds a speed and direction component
3.) The not triggering part of the description kinda implies that it looks like it is getting skipped over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your particles will move until they hit a wall, and then the next time you go through the look, they will still be in the wall, turn around again, and continue going into the wall.

If you check for collisions after your act() function this should solve the problem.

They will go into the wall, see they are in the wall, and turn around. The next loop, they will move back out of the wall, and continue on.

Comment: Thank you, now that you have mentioned that logic error, it is sticking out like a sore thumb.
Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Wait, its still not working for some reason. Described in main body.

Comment: Now that I've looked at the act() function more closely, your direction for the Y axis is being ignored. As it is, your code should only collide properly on the x axis. Post your code for Velocity, because it doesn't look like the slope function is doing what you think it is.

Comment: Try using `xPos += Math.cos(direction) * speed;` and `yPos += Math.sin(direction) * speed;` I hope you know your trigonometry.

Comment: Also, please disregard my blatant disregard for physics in that code, I use some cheating to try to keep the velocity of the particles of the different. Wait, I should have known that. This is what I get for skipping Algebra II.

Comment: Alright, that fixed some problems I didn't know I had. Now I can move on from reflecting straight back to actual reflecting.